# Compare two different files with AWK and copy values from one file to other

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk, compare

**Compare two different files with AWK and copy values from one file to other**

Hi all, I would need your help. I have two files:

**file1.csv:**

```
"count","username","start-date","status","expire-date"
"000001","TEST1","2013-05-07-16:02:07","ACTIVE","2014-05-07-16:02:07"
"000002","TEST2","2013-05-08-16:02:07","ACTIVE","2014-05-08-16:02:07"
"000003","TEST3","2013-05-09-16:02:07","ACTIVE","2015-05-09-16:02:07"
"000004","TEST4","2013-05-10-16:02:07","ACTIVE","2017-05-10-16:02:07"
"000005","TEST5","2013-05-11-12:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-08-11-12:02:07"
"000006","TEST6","2013-05-12-16:02:07","ACTIVE","2018-05-12-16:02:07"
"000007","TEST7","2013-05-13-18:05:07","ACTIVE","2016-05-13-18:05:07"
"000008","TEST8","2013-05-06-16:02:07","ACTIVE","2099-05-06-16:02:07"
"000009","TEST9","2013-05-07-13:05:07","ACTIVE","2019-05-07-13:05:07"
"000010","TEST10","2013-05-07-15:02:07","ACTIVE","2027-05-07-15:02:07
```

**file2.csv:**

```
"id","username","start-date","expire-date"<br>
"x01","TEST1","2010-05-07-16:02:07","2088-05-07-16:02:07"
"x02","TEST2","2010-05-08-16:02:07","2099-05-08-16:02:07"
"x03","TEST3","2010-05-09-16:02:07","2077-05-09-16:02:07"
"x04","TEST8","2013-05-06-16:02:07","2066-01-01-00:00:00"
"x05","TEST9","2013-05-07-13:05:07","2025-05-07-00:05:07"
```

**Output file1.csv:**

```
"count","username","start-date","status","expire-date"
"000001","TEST1","2013-05-07-16:02:07","ACTIVE","2088-05-07-16:02:07"
"000002","TEST2","2013-05-08-16:02:07","ACTIVE","2099-05-08-16:02:07"
"000003","TEST3","2013-05-09-16:02:07","ACTIVE","2077-05-09-16:02:07"
"000004","TEST4","2013-05-10-16:02:07","ACTIVE","2017-05-10-16:02:07"
"000005","TEST5","2013-05-11-12:02:07","ACTIVE","2013-08-11-12:02:07"
"000006","TEST6","2013-05-12-16:02:07","ACTIVE","2018-05-12-16:02:07"
"000007","TEST7","2013-05-13-18:05:07","ACTIVE","2016-05-13-18:05:07"
"000008","TEST8","2013-05-06-16:02:07","ACTIVE","2066-01-01-00:00:00"
"000009","TEST9","2013-05-07-13:05:07","ACTIVE","2025-05-07-00:05:07"
"000010","TEST10","2013-05-07-15:02:07","ACTIVE","2027-05-07-15:02:07
```

I need to check the usernames in booth files (file1.csv, file2.csv) and copy the "expired-date" values for every username from "file2.csv" to "file1.csv". I hope this can be done with AWK or some similar command. Thx.

Comment: Youre right! It can be done with awk or some similiar commands. ;) What you tried already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this awk one-liner: (headers are omitted, it is fixed, and easy to be added)

```
kent$  awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR==FNR{d[$2]=$4;next}$2 in d{$5=d[$2]}7' file2 file1
```

Comment: @Kent Only James Bond can use `7` to state default printing in `awk`.

Comment: @Jaypal he should use `007`.

Comment: @Kent Ha ha! Good one!! +1 for Kent and -1 for James